# How to get Siri to play songs in my library?

Tags: iphone, music, siri

Last night I was driving home and said "hey siri, play metric". Metric is a local band and I have one of their albums on my iPhone. Siri responded by subscribing me to Apple Music and playing the songs from there.

I have noticed similar things in the past. I will ask it to play an artist or album that I have on my phone, and it previously would tell me I don't have Apple Music and would not play it.

Is there some way to turn this off, or some magic phrase I can use to tell it to look only in my local library? I do not have Apple Music and will never subscribe, I simply want to listen to the (large amount) of music I already have.

Comment: I wonder if you hide Apple Music (Settings > Music > Show Apple Music) will that turn it off for you? Just a thought as I don't use Siri to play music and don't use Apple Music either...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, Siri only plays music from the Apple Music app, not from spotify or other apps.